# Fantasy book about a shed with a portal to an alternate dimension

Tags: story-identification, books

About 12 years ago, when I was young, I read a book about a boy who had a private shed/hangout. At some point the shed has a portal of sorts that brings him to a dimension where there is a war against the northern winter tribe.

Comment: When were you young? How many years ago?

Comment: I want to say about 12 years ago. I got the book From a public lirbrary so I don’t know how old it was

Comment: It's making me think of a YA book called Singularity but I can't remember the author's name. I know there was like a portal thing in a metal shed

Comment: I will look into that! Thanks!

Comment: @D.Clover: Did you ever get a chance to look into Sleator's *Singularity*?

Answer (score 2):

The story Danny Mc G is likely referring to would be William Sleator's *[Singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(Sleator_novel))*, published in 1985.

> Sixteen-year-old identical twins Harry and Barry learn that their mysterious great-uncle has died, and his house and possessions now belong to their mother. The brothers travel to Sushan, Illinois, to examine the house and its contents. Inside the cobweb-filled home, the rival brothers find mysterious animal skeletons and other odd objects. Outside Uncle Ambrose's residence, Harry and Barry find a small metal-reinforced building, which according to the accompanying keys, is called the "playhouse." When the twins explore the playhouse, they discover that the properties of time are altered inside, and the playhouse may explain the eccentricities of their great-uncle. When their quirky and cute neighbor Lucy enters their lives, competition between the twins escalates, and Harry makes a decision that will change the nature of their relationship forever.

Comment: Hmm... reading through other summaries, I think this book involves a different method of "alternate dimensions", but I'll try paging through my copy tonight.

Comment: Well that's my contribution fizzled out then! I knew I'd read Singularity a long while ago and it has a shed with a portal. I suppose there's a few similar stories

Comment: @Danny3414: It matches up for the "shed with a portal" part. :)